# Create Google Firebase Storage Bucket Programmatically Unity / C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

So I have been using the Unity Firebase Storage SDK for about a month and still can't figure out how to create a bucket from a Unity C# script if this is even possible? Is the only way to programmatically create a storage bucket is the gsutil command-line tool or one of the other google API libraries? I can't find a solution for generating a bucket through a script like you can through the other google APIs like for python, PHP and node.js.

I was thinking the Unity C# script would like some like this:

```
FirebaseStorage sotrageInstance = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

storageInstance.CreateBucket("My-Custom-Bucket-From-Unity");
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the Firebase client libraries for mobile and web clients can create a new Cloud Storage bucket.  That is a privileged operation and is reserved for only the CLI and backend libraries that are fully trusted.

If you really need to create a new bucket from a mobile client, you would probably have to create your own backend and call it from the client.  The server code could then call [createBucket (nodejs)](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#createBucket).  But you would definitely want to restrict very carefully who could do this under what circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured that was functionality was off-limits for front end libraries. My case is special because I'm creating an editor tool in Unity to help build and deploy asset bundles through firebase. I have everything setup to drag and drop a prefab in a public field and press upload content in a bucket. I'll go through the Node.js route and setup a secure restful call to a node function to create a bucket for the assetbundles.